# AutoCount Records when displaying

Tags: mysql

i want to assign a counter to records as they are fetched from a table. 
the counter should be assigned according to the Groups they belong. 
for e.g. 
table.1

```
|Groups     | Counter        |Description
-------------------------------------------
|Stationary | 1              | Pen 
|Stationary | 2              | Eraser 
|Stationary | 3              | Book 
|Stationary | 4              | Rule 
|Cars       | 1              | Benz 
|Cars       | 2              | Opel 
|Cars       | 3              | Toyota
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :)

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 
           FROM [sometbl] counter 
           WHERE t.groups = counter.groups 
           AND t.description > counter.description) AS Counter
FROM [sometbl] t
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78e07/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of variables to achieve the counter for each group

```
SELECT t1.*,
(@counter:=
CASE WHEN @group =`Groups` 
THEN  @counter +1
ELSE 1
END) counter,
@group:= `Groups`
FROM Table1 t1,
(SELECT @counter:=0,@group:='null') t 
ORDER BY `Groups`
```

### [See Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/192406/3)