# Sum records when counter increases

Tags: mysql

I am displaying some records that I need to sum the cost to get SumCost as the counter increases for a particular group of records. I will appreaciate a simple SQL code. thanks for e.g.

```
Group| Items | Cost   | SumCost| Counter
-----------------------------------------
Cars | Opel  | 50     | 50     | 1
Cars | Toyota| 60     | 110    | 2
Cars | KIA   | 40     | 150    | 3
Laps | Acer  | 30     | 30     | 1
Laps | Hp    | 45     | 75     | 2
Laps | Compaq| 20     | 95     | 3 and so on....
```

what i want is that, e.g. as the Group (Cars) are displaying its records, it should sum the cost of each car item and display it as sum/total in the SumCost column. so the SumCost of Opel is 50, the SumCost of Toyota is (cost of opel and toyota i.e. 50+60=110) and that of KIA is (opel cost + toyota cost + kia cost => 50+60+40=150) etc

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: There isn't a great SQL-only solution for what you describe.

Comment: @JakeGould: a problem can only be solved by breaking it into pieces. i started from somewhere and i got stack to an idea i want to implement. if i should display the whole issue syntax on this page, it will be difficult for people to understand and provide solution as its meaning will not be clear.

Comment: @Akeown, what piece you prepare for us in this question?

Comment: @Raging Bull: i want to achieve a goal that at a point the DBAdmin queries for that report, it will be easy to tell each Item Group SumCost for the selected items.

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: What is DBAdmin? I know 3 tool with this name... Which sql dialect you use?

Comment: @Akeown: That is exactly what I am asking. Can you show the desired result for the sample data you have shown?

Comment: Solving pieces of problems provide the greatest achievement when they are later combined! this is some of the pieces of the problem i have provided

Comment: @vp_arth: DBAdmin means database administrator

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes: I need to sum the cost to get SumCost as the counter increases for a particular group of records. just like 20+30=50; 20+30+10=60

Comment: Oh, I understand! sumCost field is what you want)

Comment: @vp_arth: yes! but it depends on the items Group for the summation that is why i just introduced the counter to give a clear picture of the issue

Comment: do you have a primary key?

Comment: The question clearly lacks any effort to solve the problem and people reading the question might feel frustrated because the person who asked the question acts as if SO users would be his/her workers. It is counter-productive to have this question on SO.

Comment: @LajosArpad, if people find it difficult to understand my questions and yet others are able to provide solutions to such questions, then i think those who cannot help cannot always help, and those who can will always support. that is why not all students can have the 1st position in class. so people who cannot support should stop marking them that they are not clear.they should rather ask for further explanations.tnx

Comment: I do not know the owners of the SQLFiddle site, but it seems their efforts towards my questions are the best solutions so far, so why should others say the questions are not clear if others are supporting. Everybody and his/her way of addressing issues and if we understand and provide solutions to our own problems, i do not think people will visit stackoverflow.com for solutions. so please allow others to have the problem-solution platform.

Comment: @Akeown, you just confirmed that I was right, you think that we are your workers. Your questions are little more than "gimme the code". There is nothing wrong for asking others to work instead of you, but this is usually paired with payment. This "I will appreaciate a simple SQL code." was very ugly from your part. As about your answer to my comment: it is not about no knowing the answer to your question, pal. It is about not wanting to help people who want me to do their work. Show more respect to the community and others will be more helpful.

Comment: @LajosArpad: please let us not have wrong intentions and argue with this issue. if you can help me please help but if you wont please do not comment. just have an over sight with my questions. thank you

Comment: @Akeown, I have no problem with your questions in general, I have only seen this one. This question lacks the minimum respect I would expect anyone to show towards this community. The very fact that you do not even try to improve your attitude is very sad. I would have expected a more constructive approach from your part, but instead of acknowledging your mistakes you are filling this comment thread with aberrations. It is my decision whether I am commenting or not. If you do not want to see this kind of comment in the future, then you might consider improving your attitude and questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you ask, exactly:

```
SELECT 
IF(t.counter=1, @sum:=0,null) _,
@sum:=@sum+t.cost sum, 
t.*
FROM A t;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baeb6/4)

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66171/1) without counter, by group changing

I review another your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871973/autocount-records-when-displaying) and find very useful its answer
Here same solution for sum counting:

```
SELECT *, 
  (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM sometbl counter 
   WHERE t.groups = counter.groups AND t.id >= counter.id) AS cost_sum
FROM sometbl t
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e00e91/2)

Comment: pls, is there another way instead of using sql variables? if the fields/coulmns can be manipulated because mysql gives error when converting the codes to Views table. am trying to follow your syntax by changing the variables to columns/fields from my tables.

Comment: I don't know... may be, but I can't make it on fly...

Comment: realy, wow...more help please

Comment: You should save the state between rows... aggregate sum... reset sum... How else?

Comment: @Akeown, I add another fiddle, without counter, with group field... may be it be some more useful...

Comment: i really apreaciate your inputs, but i really want to avoid the use of sql variables as it prevents mysql executor not to execute the query to a View table. i even wanted to use the Group's counter to perform the summation but is still giving me logic error and i hope you can also come up with such idea also. thank you

Comment: i really apreaciate your efforts but mysql continue to give the error for using the variables especially setting @sum:=0 as i want to convert it to a view. thank you

Comment: @Akeown, I update it, please check

Comment: great work friend, your samples are so wonderful and awesome. i really appreciate all your contributions. 5 stars! thanks